# Ubuntu Quick settings panel doesn't look right after updating to 22.10

Tags: system-tray, 22.10

I updated from Ubuntu 22.04 to 22.10 yesterday and the quick settings panel does not look right. It has huge out of place icons and looks nothing the sleek modern looking settings panel in the screenshots for 22.10. Request to you help fix this on my PC.

[The icons looks huge and out of place](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F4oG9.png)

Comment: Ask UBuntu can't help you " fix it". 22.10 is an interim version and you should report it perhaps as a bug for the developers to deal with.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I report a bug?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug)

Answer (score 0):

I have the EXACT same problem.  It has existed from 22.10 and into 23.04.  Interestingly, in another ubuntu build this problem does not occur.  It only happens when the user is logged out.  If its just a lock screen then this Quick Settings panel is properly stylized.  So it appears to be a permissions issue.

I also dont think its a bug considering one of my ubuntu systems works just fine while the  others has the same problem as yours (exact look as ur image).

I am still investigating.

Try installing this extension to see about recofiguring this settings menu which could potentially coax the menu back to working again: https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/5443/quick-settings-button-remover/